# How to enrich a TraversableOnce with my own generic map?

Tags: scala

I am trying to enrich all TraversableOnce[String] objects, and I can't figure out the right syntax for building iterators. This is what I have so far:

```
class Exclaimer[R <: TraversableOnce[String]](val lines:R) {
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def exclaim(implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[R,String,R]):R = {
    val b = bf(lines)
    lines.foreach(b += _)
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def WrapExclaimer[R <: TraversableOnce[String]](lines:R) = new Exclaimer(lines)
```

It works fine for collections (i.e. it returns an collection of the same class as I gave it), but it doesn't work for iterators, because it `Cannot construct a collection of type Iterator[java.lang.String] with elements of type String based on a collection of type Iterator[java.lang.String]`. How do I fix this? I'm using Scala 2.9 (edit: I mistakenly wrote 2.8).

Here is some sample output:

```
scala> List("a","b","c").exclaim
res5: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> Vector("a","b","c").exclaim
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[java.lang.String] = Vector(a, b, c)

scala> List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim
<console>:10: error: Cannot construct a collection of type Iterator[java.lang.String] with elements of type String based on a collection of type Iterator[java.lang.String].
              List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### General solution for 2.10

You should use `exclaim[That](implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[R, String, That])` instead of `CanBuildFrom[R,String,R]`. Note also that there is more general way to extend collection-like classes - `IsTraversableOnce` (and also `IsTraversableLike`)

```
import collection.generic.IsTraversableOnce
import collection.GenTraversableOnce

class Exclaimer[A, Repr](val lines: GenTraversableOnce[A]) {
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def exclaim[That](implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[Repr, String, That], e: A =:= String): That = {
    val b = bf()
    lines.foreach(s => b += e(s))
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def wrapExclaimer[Repr](r: Repr)(implicit fr: IsTraversableOnce[Repr]): Exclaimer[fr.A,Repr] =
  new Exclaimer[fr.A, Repr](fr.conversion(r))
```

This method works with `Array`:

```
Array("a","b","c").exclaim
// Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

### Fixed initial implementation

Here is your initial implementation (fixed). It works with `Iterator`, but fails on `Array` since `Array` is not `TraversableOnce`:

```
class Exclaimer[R <: TraversableOnce[String]](val lines:R) {
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def exclaim[That](implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[R,String,That]):That = {
    val b = bf(lines)
    lines.foreach(b += _)
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def WrapExclaimer[R <: TraversableOnce[String]](lines:R) = new Exclaimer(lines)

scala> List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> Array("a","b","c").exclaim
<console>:10: error: value exclaim is not a member of Array[String]
              Array("a","b","c").exclaim
                                 ^
```

### CanBuildFrom

There is no `IsTraversableOnce` in `scala` `2.9.3`, so you have to use fixed version of your initial approach. But you'll get `TraversableOnce` instead of `Iterator`.

```
List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim
// scala.collection.TraversableOnce[String] = non-empty iterator
```

To get `Iterator` you have to create your own implicit `CanBuildFrom` like this:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.mutable.Builder
import collection.immutable.VectorBuilder

implicit def iteratorCbf[A, B] = new CanBuildFrom[Iterator[A], B, Iterator[B]]{
  def apply(): Builder[B, Iterator[B]] = new Builder[B, Iterator[B]]{
    private[this] val inner = new VectorBuilder[B]
    def +=(elem: B) = {
      inner += elem
      this
    }
    def clear(): Unit = inner.clear()
    def result(): Iterator[B] = inner.result().iterator
  }
  def apply(i: Iterator[A]) = apply()
}
```

No you'll get `Iterator[String]` instead of `TraversableOnce[String]`:

```
List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim
// Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

You should add implicit `iteratorCbf` method into companion object of your `Exclaimer` class.

Comment: When I type in this second Exclaimer (your fixed version of my initial implementation), I get a different result: List("a","b","c").iterator.exclaim returns a TraversableOnce[String] for me. What do I need to do, to make it return an Iterator[String]? (I just realized I'm using Scala 2.9.3, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: @DamonJW: I'm getting `Iterator[String]` on `2.10.3` and there is no `IsTraversableOnce` in `2.9.3`, so yes, it makes a difference.

Comment: I can't upgrade to 2.10 at the moment. Do you know if there's something I can pull in to give me the CanBuildFrom[Iterator,_,Iterator] I need?

Comment: @DamonJW: I'm trying to fix it on `2.9.3` now, but I guess it's almost impossible. You could always create your own implicit `CanBuildFrom[Iterator,_,Iterator]`, but it's not a general solution.

Comment: @DamonJW: actually this solution is not so bad, you should use your implementation (fixed version) with implicit `CanBuildFrom[Iterator,_,Iterator]` in scope.

Comment: I wanted my Exclaimer class to support Iterators, in case the iteration is over a gigantic dataset that won't fit into memory. Is this possible, using Builder.result()? Or do I need a more generic way of constructing the output? I tried reading bits of Iterator.scala source code, but it was beyond me.

Comment: @DamonJW: I guess it's impossible with `CanBuildFrom`. You could create more specific transformation for iterators: `implicit def wrapExclaimerIterator(lines: Iterator[String]) = new IteratorExclaimer(lines)`. You could also take a look at `scalaz` - using `Functor` typeclass you could add your own method to all classes with this typeclass. There is no `Functor` for `Iterator`, but you could use `Stream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest answer, I think, is *Don't try to enrich TraversableOnce with a generic map*. The point of TraversableOnce is that it covers both Iterators and Collections -- but the only way to generically enrich a TraversableOnce (with Scala 2.10) is to turn the iterator into a collection and back into an iterator, which defeats the point of the iterator (or at least one point: being able to stream huge datasets without loading them all into memory).

I had naively thought that because Iterator.map and Collection.map have the same syntax, they had a common implementation, and so I was trying to find a common implementation for my Exclaimer map. However, looking at the Scala source code, we see that Iterator.map and Collection.map have different implementations:

```
// Implementation of map in TraversableOnce[+A] implicit typecast to MonadOps[+A]
def map[B](f: A => B): TraversableOnce[B] = trav.toIterator map f

// Implementation of map in Iterator[+A]
def map[B](f: A => B): Iterator[B] = new AbstractIterator[B] {
  def hasNext = self.hasNext
  def next() = f(self.next())
}

// Implementation of map in TraversableLike[+A, +Repr]
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  def builder = { // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
    val b = bf(repr)
    b.sizeHint(this)
    b
  }
  val b = builder
  for (x <- this) b += f(x)
  b.result
}
```

Moral: If the Scala designers decided not to write a generic map function for TraversableOnce, then I shouldn't try to either.

Here is the code I ended up with, thanks to @senia.

```
class TraversableExclaimer[R <: Traversable[String]](val lines:R) {
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def exclaim[That](implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[R,String,That]):That = {
    val b = bf(lines)
    lines.foreach(b += _+"!")
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def WrapTraversableExclaimer[R <: Traversable[String]](lines:R) = new TraversableExclaimer[R](lines)

class IteratorExclaimer[T <: String](val lines:Iterator[T]) {
  def exclaim:Iterator[T] = new Object with Iterator[T] {
    def hasNext = lines.hasNext
    def next() = (lines.next()+"!").asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
implicit def WrapIteratorExclaimer(lines:Iterator[String]) = new IteratorExclaimer[String](lines)
```