# Scala method to side effect on map and return it

Tags: scala

What is the best way to apply a function to each element of a `Map` and at the end return the same `Map`, unchanged, so that it can be used in further operations?

I'd like to avoid:

```
myMap.map(el => {
  effectfullFn(el)
  el
})
```

to achieve syntax like this:

```
myMap
  .mapEffectOnKV(effectfullFn)
  .foreach(println)
```

`map` is not what I'm looking for, because I have to specify what comes out of the map (as in the first code snippet), and I don't want to do that.

I want a special operation that *knows/assumes* that the map elements should be returned without change after the side-effect function has been executed.

In fact, this would be so useful to me, I'd like to have it for `Map`, `Array`, `List`, `Seq`, `Iterable`... The general idea is to peek at the elements to do something, then automatically return these elements.

The real case I'm working on looks like this:

```
 calculateStatistics(trainingData, indexMapLoaders)
   .superMap { (featureShardId, shardStats) =>
      val outputDir = summarizationOutputDir + "/" + featureShardId
      val indexMap = indexMapLoaders(featureShardId).indexMapForDriver()
      IOUtils.writeBasicStatistics(sc, shardStats, outputDir, indexMap)
    }
```

Once I have calculated the statistics for each shard, I want to append the side effect of saving them to disk, and then just return those statistics, without having to create a `val` and having that `val`'s name be the last statement in the function, e.g.:

```
val stats = calculateStatistics(trainingData, indexMapLoaders)
stats.foreach { (featureShardId, shardStats) =>
  val outputDir = summarizationOutputDir + "/" + featureShardId
  val indexMap = indexMapLoaders(featureShardId).indexMapForDriver()
  IOUtils.writeBasicStatistics(sc, shardStats, outputDir, indexMap)
}
stats
```

It's probably not very hard to implement, but I was wondering if there was something in Scala already for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate scala map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364468/how-to-iterate-scala-map)

Comment: No - I think it's different. I'm trying to append something that has side effects in a chain of operations on the map.

Comment: I would advise against that. You'd be needlessly iterating through the map multiple times. Just iterate once and do whatever you need to do to the key-value pairs inside the single iteration.

Comment: This is sometimes called `tap`.

Comment: @Yawar - I added my real case. I don't think I would iterate multiple times.

Comment: OK. I don't think `Map` has a method for this--the basic operations are `foreach` and `map`. But--you can probably use `ensuring` to do it, it's just slightly clunky because you have to make sure you return `true` at the end. `ensuring` is meant to be used as design-by-contract tool. Anyway: `calculateStatistics(...) ensuring { _ foreach { case (k, v) => ... }; true }`.

Comment: @Yawar - not being clunky in any way is of the essence here :-)

Comment: OK. There's a Unix tool called `tee` that takes an input and directs it to two different outputs. We can adapt the concept here. I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yes - between `tee` and `tap`, we are going to end up finding something :-) Ideally, the implementation should be as widely applicable as possible (e.g. not just to `Map` :-) I'm not sure what is the right level for that. dk14 is suggesting `TraversableOnce`.

Comment: As it turns out, tee and tap are pretty much the same thing 

Comment: I know - just found the sounds funny :-)

Comment: Rex Kerr refers to is as the [KestrelPattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231509/what-is-the-added-value-of-the-kestrel-functional-programming-design-pattern-s) and uses `tap`. [I prefer `tee`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815793/filter-and-report-multiple-predicates/41816281#41816281)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605500/idiomatic-way-of-print-and-return-value-at-the-same-time-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function cannot be effectful by definition, so I wouldn't expect anything convenient in scala-lib. However, you can write a wrapper:

```
def tap[T](effect: T => Unit)(x: T) = {
  effect(x)
  x
}
```

Example:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
         .map(tap(el => el._1 + 5 -> el._2))
         .foreach(println)
(1,1)
(2,2)
```

You can also define an implicit:

```
implicit class TapMap[K,V](m: Map[K,V]){
  def tap(effect: ((K,V)) => Unit): Map[K,V] = m.map{x =>
    effect(x)
    x
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2).tap(el => el._1 + 5 -> el._2).foreach(println)
(1,1)
(2,2)
```

To abstract more, you can define this implicit on `TraversableOnce`, so it would be applicable to `List`, `Set` and so on if you need it:

```
implicit class TapTraversable[Coll[_], T](m: Coll[T])(implicit ev: Coll[T] <:< TraversableOnce[T]){
  def tap(effect: T => Unit): Coll[T] = {
    ev(m).foreach(effect)
    m
  }
}

scala> List(1,2,3).tap(println).map(_ + 1)
1
2
3
res24: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> Map(1 -> 1).tap(println).toMap //`toMap` is needed here for same reasons as it needed when you do `.map(f).toMap`
(1,1)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> Set(1).tap(println)
1
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)
```

It's more useful, but requires some "mamba-jumbo" with types, as `Coll[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]` doesn't work (Scala 2.12.1), so I had to use an evidence for that.

You can also try `CanBuildFrom` approach: [How to enrich a TraversableOnce with my own generic map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635733/how-to-enrich-a-traversableonce-with-my-own-generic-map)

---

Overall recommendation about dealing with passthrough side-effects on iterators is to use `Stream`s (scalaz/fs2/monix) and `Task`, so they've got an `observe` (or some analog of it) function that does what you want in async (if needed) way.

---

My answer before you provided example of what you want

You can represent effectful computation without side-effects and have distinct values that represent state before and after:

```
scala> val withoutSideEffect = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
withoutSideEffect: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)                                                                       

scala> val withSideEffect = withoutSideEffect.map(el => el._1 + 5 -> (el._2 + 5))
withSideEffect: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(6 -> 6, 7 -> 7)

scala> withoutSideEffect //unchanged
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)

scala> withSideEffect //changed
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(6 -> 6, 7 -> 7)
```

Comment: `.map(tap` !! How about just `.tap`?

Comment: @Frank already added this (I was editing answer when you commented :)). However original tap is more universal as it doesn't care about type of container.

Comment: `implicit TapMap` is nice - can it be generalized to anything that can be iterated on?

Comment: `TraversableOnce`, yes, but author did ask about maps only :)

Comment: Well not quite - the author said he would want to have that functionality for a bunch of data structures :-)

Comment: @dk14 - yes OP is pretty active. OP is thinking about choosing dk14's reply as The Answer, but Yawar is now also in the running. _Tee_ versus _tap_. Who will provide the most generic, most widely useful form?

Comment: It looks like we have a *winner*! Congratulations!

Comment: Omg! I'm out. I added `GenTraversableOnce` version. That's it. I can only recommend scalaz/fs2 `Task` for side-effects

Comment: @dk14 - you won! `TapTraversable` is right on the money! Great job!

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I've added more useful version of `TapTraversable`

Comment: While this is very useful (I came here looking for the same solution) folks should keep in mind that if you are working on a strict data structure you'll be recreating the data structure with each `tap`.  If you don't need the intermediate results you will want to use tap on an iterator or a view to avoid the reconstruction.

Comment: @LannyRipple To clarify your recommendation about View: TapTraversable version, I guess should suffice that (as it’s based on foreach). Though, as I recall, recent scala-collections removed (deprecated?) TraversableOnce in favor of Iterable, so implementations should be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Also, calling tap on Iterator would probably drain it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the concept you're after is similar to the Unix `tee`
utility--take an input and direct it to two different outputs. (`tee`
gets its name from the shape of the letter 'T', which looks like a
pipeline from left to right with another line branching off downwards.)
Here's the Scala version:

```
package object mypackage {
  implicit class Tee[A](a: A) extends AnyVal {
    def tee(f: A => Unit): A = { f(a); a }
  }
}
```

With that, we can do:

```
calculateStatistics(trainingData, indexMapLoaders) tee { stats =>
  stats foreach { case (featureShardId, shardStats) =>
    val outputDir = summarizationOutputDir + "/" + featureShardId
    val indexMap = indexMapLoaders(featureShardId).indexMapForDriver()
    IOUtils.writeBasicStatistics(sc, shardStats, outputDir, indexMap)
  }
}
```

Note that as defined, `Tee` is very generic--it can do an effectful
operation on any value and then return the original passed-in value.

Comment: Hmmmm - How about rolling in the foreach, so that the syntax becomes lighter? This one is very general, it is very nice from that point view, but I would be ok assuming that `A` can be iterated on.

Answer (score 1):

Call `foreach` on your `Map` with your effectfull function. You original `Map` will not be changed as `Maps` in scala are immutable.

```
val myMap = Map(1 -> 1)
myMap.foreach(effectfullFn)
```

If you are trying to chain this operation, you can use `map`

```
myMap.map(el => {
    effectfullFn(el)
    el
})
```